# WP AJAX not updating update_user_meta (with multiple values)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created a modal for logged in users only and when a user clicks on the `close` icon, I wish to update user meta field of that particular user.

My modal code looks like this:

```
function theme_notification_popup() {       
    $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', true ); ?>

    <div id="my-id" class="uk-modal" data-uk-modal="{center:true}">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
            <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close" data-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $level[0] ); ?>-notification-read"></a>
            <h4>Title</h4></div>    
            ...content...   
        </div>
    </div>          
<?php }
add_action ('wp_footer', 'theme_notification_popup');
```

I'm using the `data-id` attribute that stores the info needed to update the user_meta.

Since AJAX is the way to handle this, here's my AJAX code

```
jQuery( 'document' ).ready( function( $ ) {

      jQuery('#uk-modal').on('click', '.uk-modal-close', function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();

            var levelRead = $('.uk-modal-close').attr('data-id');

                $.ajax( {
                    url : ajax_url,
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: {  
                        action  : 'km_ajax',
                        'data-id': levelRead, 
                    }
                } )
                .success( function( results ) {
                   // console.log( 'User Meta Updated!' );
                   console.log( levelRead );
                } )
                .fail( function( data ) {
                    console.log( data.responseText );
                    console.log( 'Request failed: ' + data.statusText );
                } );

            return false; 
        });

    } );
```

And here's the required callback

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_km_ajax', 'km_ajax_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_km_ajax', 'km_ajax_callback' );
function km_ajax_callback() {

    if( ! empty( $_POST['data-id'] ) ) {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( empty( $user_id ) ) { 
            return false; 
        }

        $level = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', true );

        $new_val =  sanitize_text_field( $_POST['data-id'] );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', array( $level[0], $new_val ) ); 
    }

    wp_die();   

}
```

In console I see that the AJAX is successful when a user clicks on the `close` button.  However, the user_meta doesn't get updated. This means there must be a mistake in my `km_ajax_callback()` function. Or somewhere else?

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

just change your update_user_meta method :

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', $author_val);
```

Check here update user meta method:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/

Answer (score 0):

I found out where the problem lies; There's nothing wrong with the AJAX code after all.

I also created an extra function

```
function theme_achievements() {

    $value = user_total_posts( get_current_user_id() )

    if( $value >= '0' && $value <= '499' ) { 
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'author_level', array( 'lvl-1', '' ) );
    } elseif( $value >= '500' && $value <= '999' ) { 
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'author_level', array( 'lvl-2', '' ) );
    } else {
        ...
    }

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_achievements' );
```

This function above runs everytime, overriding the AJAX update. Any ideas on a better way to handle the function above? Instead of using `wp_head`, is there something else?